# Show that for $f(s,t)=(s^2+t)^{-a}$ the function $f^b$ is integrable over $(0,1)\times(0,T)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lp-spaces

This should be a rather simple question, but I wasn't able to figure out what's the trick to find a suitable upper bound: Given $a\in(1/2,3/2)$, $b\in[1,1/(a-1/2))$ and $T>0$, how can we show that for $f(s,t):=(s^2+t)^{-a}$, $s\in(0,1)$, $t\in(0,T)$, the function $f^b$ is integrable over $(0,1)\times(0,T)$?

Comment: The only potential problem is the singularity. But for small values, we can estimate $$\vert f(s,t)\vert \leq \Vert (s,t)\Vert^{-2a}.$$ Passing to spherical coordinates yields the desired result as $$2ab\leq 2-\frac{1}{a-\frac{1}{2}}<2.$$

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you for your comment. Unless I'm missing something, this is not enough, since we've only assumed that $b<1/(a-1/2)$, while your suggestion requires $b<1/a$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz What do you mean by "other regions"? So, you're not sure whether the claim is true?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Could you elaborate on your approach? How does it help that we've got your estimate "for small values" and why do we need to pass to spherical coordinates?

Comment: Because away from the origin it is obviously integrable as we integrate a continuous function, bounded function over a bounded domain. You don't have to pass to spherical coordinates, but there it is clear that the integral converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we assume $a,b>0$. For convergence purposes, it is enough to consider the integral over the cube $(0,1]^2$. By Fubini-Tonelli's theorem:

1. If $ab\neq1$
   $$\int^1_0\int^1_0\frac{1}{(s^2+t)^{ab}}\,dtds=\int^1_0\frac{1}{1-ab}\big((s^2+1)^{1-ab} - s^{2(1-ab)}\big)\,ds$$
   The integral $$\int^1_0\frac{1}{s^{2(ab-1)}}\,ds$$ converges if $2(ab-1)<1$ and diverges if $2(ab-1)\geq1$. The integral $$\int^1_0(s^2+1)^{1-ab}\,ds$$ is convergent since $1\leq s^2 +1\leq 2$ for $0\leq s\leq 1$.
2. If $ab=1$
   $$\int^1_0\int^1_0\frac{1}{(s^2+t)}\,dtds=\int^1_0\log(s^2+1)-2\log(s)\,ds$$
   The integral is convergent since $\int^1_0|\log s|\,ds =-(s\log(s)-s)|^1_0=1<\infty$.

Thus, the integral in question converges iff $2(ab-1)<1$, i. e., $ab<\tfrac32$.

Here is a plot of the function $\phi(a)=\frac{3}{2a}$ (in black), $\psi(a)=\frac{1}{a-1/2}$ (in blue) and $\xi(a)\equiv1$ (in red) for $\frac12 <a\leq \frac32$. Notice that convergence in the region of interest for the OP occurs between the black and the red plots, that is $\{(a,b): \frac12<a<\frac32,\, 1\leq b\leq \frac{3}{2a}\}$.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort. How do you obtain that $\int^1_0(s^2+1)^{1-ab}\,ds$ is convergent?

Comment: Because the integrand is bounded by $1$ and the region is bounded.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Why should the integrand be bounded by $1$? This is only the case, when $ab>1$, isn't it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's still not clear to me why $\int^1_0\frac{1}{s^{2(ab-1)}}\,ds$ exists. I agree to what you wrote: This integral is finite, if $\color{red}{0<}2(ab-1)<1$, and infinite, if $2(ab-1)\ge1$. The case $2(ab-1)<0$ is easy to handle, since then the integral is bounded by $1$. But in the other case, i.e. $2(ab-1)>0$, we still would need to show that the assumptions on $a,b$ imply that $2(ab-1)<1$. How do we see that this actually holds?

Comment: That's what I wrote: If $2(ab-1)<0$, then the integral is bounded by $1$. But you didn't get my point for the other case. I know that $\int_0^1\frac1{x^p}=\frac1{1-p}$ for all $p\in(0,1)$. But how does this help to answer the question in my post, **unless** we are able to show that the assumptions imposed on $a,b$ ensure that we've actually got $2(ab-1)<1$?

Comment: I only restricted to $p\in(0,1)$, since $p<0$ is trivial. Could you tell me whether you think the claim in the question is correct? The assumptions are $a\in(1/2,3/2)$ and $b\in[1,1/a-1/2)$. Does it hold that $2(ab-1)<1$ then?